# How was kernel written?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

Running a program in kernel mode forbids using standard C library because the only thing your program linked to is kernel itself. So I'm allowed to use functions defined in kernel. But kernel itself is a program written in C and compiled for some particular architecture. And it shouldn't use C standard library, but it also shouldn't use any drivers since drivers are loadable modules. So my question is what actual C functions are used when writing a kernel? How can you interact with hardware not through kernel? Don't say me to look at sources it's too next level for me, TY.

Answer (score 2):

The Unix kernel has traditionally included *some* assembly language code. 
I haven’t looked at its source code recently,
but I suspect that that’s still true.

See [How does a driver actually communicate with a hardware device?](https://superuser.com/q/867009/354511)
for an overview of that topic. 
The answers to that question discuss two kinds of computer architecture. 
On a system that uses port-mapped I/O (PMIO),
the kernel *must* be written partly in assembly language —
although you may be able to get by with a couple very short routines. 
On a system that uses memory-mapped I/O (MMIO),
even device drivers can be written entirely in C. 
All they need to do is declare a pointer,
set it equal to the virtual address of the device,
and then use it to manipulate the device as if it were accessing memory.

Answer (score 0):

Not all drivers are loadable modules, being loadable is simply an option but some crucial drivers are not dynamically loaded, they are part of the kernel.

Comment: So then the question is how drivers were written

Comment: With `vi`, likely.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel reproduces a whole bunch of the functionality provided by libc statically, within itself.

Just like in user-mode C programming, a function can be defined in one compilation unit and another unit can simply reference it (usually via a header file), the compiler will make it an undefined reference, and the linker will link it with the compilation unit that actually provides the symbol.

Loading kernel modules works on the same principle as [dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) and it's described here:
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/modules/modules.html

Comment: It's all just C, you see.

Comment: I mean, is there any functions in C which are not implemented neither in kernel nor in standard library? What is the most "naked"(assembly-like) C only compiler knows what to do with ?

Comment: @user30167 You can use any standard types known by the compiler to implement functions to manipulate data (all the basic operators like: +,-,*,/,=,^,|,&,...).  In order to do useful stuff with the data, you need the drivers implemented by the kernel which are also accessible by libc (which uses syscalls to the kernel).  There is also bare metal programming, but that will typically require some assembly language or a specific compiler.